# How to change single value in a data.frame (value being a new level)?

Tags: r, levels

I want to change a single value in a data.frame, which is NA using this code `df[307, 1] <- 231`. However, I get the warning message

```
warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 231) :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

As I understood right, the level `231` is not within the levels of the variable (`[,1]` first column). What can I do to solve this problem? Add new level `231`? Or another way to change this single value. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: The column is `factor` class.  Change that to `character` or add the level in the existing factor column and then replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @akrun noted in the comments:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b"))
x[3] <- "c"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = "c") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
# one solution:
x <- factor(c("a", "b"))
x <- factor(c(as.character(x), "c"))

# a second solution:
x <- factor(c("a", "b"))
levels(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")
x[3] <- "c"
```